# Web scraping - Password required | Python, BeautifulSoup, requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to perform web scraping using Python, beatifulsoup and requests. I firstly need to log into the page and then request the following page from where I would like to perform the web scraping.

I can say that I login successfully as the status code is 200. However, when I request the next page after I log in, I do not get the whole content.

Specifically, I get this line instead of multiple nested divs.
`<div id="app"></div>`
actual content look like the following.
[image]

My code is the following. I would like to ask you whether I’m missing anything in order to get all nested divs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

login_data = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'sp-login': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://api.private.zscaler.com/base/api/zpa/signin"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers= headers)
    print(r.content)
    print(r.ok)
    print(r.status_code)

    r2 = requests.get("https://admin.private.zscaler.com/#dashboard/usersDashboard")
    print(r2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The web app you are trying to **scrape** might be an SPA (Single Page Application) built with something like React \ Vue \ Angular.

BeautifulSoup wouldn't work in this case, because you need to run javascript on page to build DOM.

You would have to use something like Selenium to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Azamat.

I did try with Selenium but with no luck.

My code is the following
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://admin.private.zscaler.com/")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("myusername")
password.send_keys("pass")

driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

Even thought the id of the fields are the ones I am using, the code does not work as expected.
I am receiving:
no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: @GeorgiosZervakis comments are very bad for pasting code. You can update your question or open a new one (and tag me in the comments if you want). Try opening the website in selenium browser yourself, letting it load and then run a `find_element_by_id`. If that works then just add a `wait()` after `get` in your code.